# requisição remota com php jQuery-autoComplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer requisição *remota* de um arquivo `PHP` com o plugin [jQuery-autoComplete](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete), porém não esta dando certo. O plugin em questão e esse aqui: [jQuery-autoComplete](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete). Quero utilizar ele por ser bem simples, leve e atende ao que preciso.

A requisição e feita assim:

```
$('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({
minChars: 2,
source: function(term, suggest){
    term = term.toLowerCase();
    var choices = ['ActionScript', 'AppleScript', 'Asp', ...];
    var matches = [];
    for (i=0; i<choices.length; i++)
        if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(choices[i]);
    suggest(matches);
}
});
```

No `var choices` preciso colocar o arquivo `PHP` que vai retornar o resultado. O problema e que não funciona. Já dei uma olhada na documentação e não tem um exemplo complete. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: requisição remota seria o que? um endereço remoto? ou o arquivo de busca é local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [jQuery-autoComplete](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete), tem um modelo básico de requisição [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) que pode ser feito assim:

**Html**

```
<input type="text" name="q" />
```

---

**Javascript**

```
$('input[name="aj"]').autoComplete({
    source: function(term, response){
        $.getJSON('busca.php', { q: term }, 
                     function(data){ response(data); });
    }
});
```

<sub>**Observação:** aonde está `busca.php` troque pelo endereço do arquivo que vai gerar os dados</sub>

---

**`Busca.php`**

O arquivo deve retornar um `Json` de um `array` simples do seu código em `PHP`, ***exemplo***:

```
['aaa','aaaa','aaaaa']; // ou array('aaa','aaaa','aaaaa');
```

o código exemplo como não tem referencias na sua pergunta seria:

```
<?php

    $array['aaa'] = ['aaa','aaaa','aaaaa'];
    $array['bbb'] = ['bbb','bbbb','bbbbb'];
    $result = isset($_GET['q']) ? $array[$_GET['q']] : [];

    return json_encode($result);
```

O código funciona assim, ao digitar três *aaa* ele pega os valores `['aaa','aaaa','aaaaa']` e mostra na caixa os 3 itens e assim também é com os *bbb*. Se quiser colocar busca no banco deve adaptar essa ideia.

***Referencia:*** [autoComplete - An extremely lightweight completion suggester plugin for jQuery.](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)

Comment: muito bom, amanhã sedo eu vou testar, e se funcionar eu marco a resposta ok. Vou tentar adaptar consulta em BD mysql. Amanha posto aqui se deu certo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @HugoBorges Ok, o código é funcional ... se pode usar como teste e depois partir para adaptação ...

Comment: eu testei o código aqui e funcionou, porém tive que mudar a seguinte linha 'echo json_encode($result);'. Mia uma vez, muito obrigado.